# Google Sheets - getting feedback from a dynamic sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, sidebar

I've created a sidebar in Google Sheets that populates itself with elements from the Sheet itself. It has to do this because some of these values will change quite often - as such, it doesn't use HTML.

Code for the part of it that's important is below:

```
//build the sidebar
var UIInstance=UiApp.createApplication()
  .setTitle('Please choose Plant below:')
  .setWidth(250);
//get the values over
var MaxRow=250;
var LookIn=0;
var GoHere="http://www.google.co.uk";
var L1; var L2; var L3;
for(LookIn=1;LookIn<MaxRow;LookIn++)
{
  L1=sheet.getRange("AB" + LookIn);
  L2=sheet.getRange("AC" + LookIn);
  L3=sheet.getRange("AD" + LookIn);
  if(L1.getValues()!="")
  {
    UIInstance.add(UIInstance.createLabel("_"));
    UIInstance.add(UIInstance.createHTML("<b>" + L1.getValues() + "</b>"));
  }
  if(L2.getValues()!="")
  {
    UIInstance.add(UIInstance.createLabel(' - - + ' + L2.getValues()));
  }
  if(L3.getValues()!="")
  {
    UIInstance.add(UIInstance.createHTML(" - - - - - + <a href=''www.google.co.uk''>" + L3.getValues() + "</a>",false));
  }
}
//add the sidebar
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showSidebar(UIInstance);
```

What I'd like to do is, whenever someone clicks one of the values (ideally one of the L3 values), it inserts that value into the current cell. Unfortunately I'm having trouble getting anything that does that working (at the moment it's just got a Google link in there, but even that's not showing up).

Does anyone have any ideas? Again, the sidebar has to be created dynamically (which it already is).

Comment: You can create dynamic content with HTML.  You need to use `google.script.run` in order to write something from the sidebar to the sheet.  [Link to Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Answer (score 0):

Managed it using radio buttons. Only issue now is getting the parameters.

```
//build the sidebar
  var UIInstance=UiApp.createApplication()
      .setTitle('Please choose Plant below:')
      .setWidth(250);
  //get the values over
  var MaxRow=250;
  var LookIn=0;
  var L1; var L2; var L3;
  for(LookIn=1;LookIn<MaxRow;LookIn++)
  {
    L1=sheet.getRange("AB" + LookIn);
    L2=sheet.getRange("AC" + LookIn);
    L3=sheet.getRange("AD" + LookIn);
    if(L1.getValues()!=""){UIInstance.add(UIInstance.createLabel("_")); UIInstance.add(UIInstance.createHTML("<b>" + L1.getValues() + "</b>"));}
    if(L2.getValues()!=""){UIInstance.add(UIInstance.createHTML("<b> > > " + L2.getValues() + "</b>"));}
    if(L3.getValues()!="")
    {
      var RadioHandler=UIInstance.createServerChangeHandler('radioButtonsChange');
      UIInstance.add(UIInstance.createRadioButton("MyButton").setId(L3.getValues).setText(L3.getValues()).addClickHandler(RadioHandler));
      UIInstance.add(UIInstance.createLabel(""));
    }
  }
  //add the sidebar
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(UIInstance);
}
```